# LLVM- Replacing instructions assigned to a reference

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to understand how I can replace an instruction with LLVM and ensure that the reference that was set equal to the original instruction can be reset to the new instruction I create (for the life of me, I'm having a really hard time navigating the LLVM documentation)

Say I have instruction i and I know it's what I want to replace- I'm doing this

```
    BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, value, operand, "", i);
    i->eraseFromParent();
```

To create my new instrution and place it before i, the instruction I'm replacing. Then I remove i.

My issue is that the old instruction was set to a register, and later %2 is reused for a store (like below, for example).

```
%2 = mul %0, 2
```

In removing instruction i I removed the entire line, including %2, and I'm assuming my new instruction is set to some other register. How can I take care of this? I've seen that there is a ReplaceInstWithInst call I can use, but I have no idea if it would solve my problem/ how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no registers or variables in the LLVM intermediate language, nor are there any assignments. Confused? I recommend reading more about [SSA form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form).

In particular, I recommend avoiding thinking in names (%something). Names are only useful for the textual representation of the intermediate language (.ll files), they don't have too many uses when you use LLVM APIs directly.

In any case, replaceinstwithinst is a good way to replace one instruction with another. What it actually does is replace all the uses of the old instruction with uses of the new one.

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I needed- I had hoped ReplaceInstWithInst did that but couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere